# What are the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, communities-list

Is there any place where I can look at all the Stack Exchange sites? That is, I would like to have a list of all the sites available with Stack Exchange under the hood. If no such list exists right now, I think it would be a good idea to have one where users can configure what all they need to see in a dashboard view.

Comment: Well, the easiest place to start is to scroll down to the bottom of the page and check out the footer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [StackExchange 2.0 sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) on stackexchange.com - and also up there in the "StackExchange" dropdown at the top of the page.

There's [a wiki of SE 1 sites on SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites), although some are now running OSQA or an alternate engine I think.

Comment: As of a few days ago, the wiki link (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) no longer exists. All `meta.stackexchange.com` URLs redirect to the MSO main page.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a full list of SE 2.0 sites (including those in closed beta) maintained at http://metaoverflow.appspot.com/sites

[MetaOverflow](http://metaoverflow.appspot.com/) also provides RSS feeds which you can use to keep informed when new sites become available.

Comment: But that's just the 2.0 sites straight from the API. The StackExchange 1 sites e.g. mathoverflow.com are missing

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that the list that is maintained is for SE 2.0 sites only.